# Puppeteer: how evaluate code in iframe context when I have ElementHandler of Iframe

Tags: iframe, puppeteer

In Puppeteer there is `page.frames()` to got all frame in the page ( include the main frame) then I can use `page.frames()[0].evaluate( _=> 'run some code')` in the context of the iframe.

But how I can do the same when I have `iframeHandler = page.$('ifram#id')` ?

[In the documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-elementhandleevaluatepagefunction-args) this is ElementHandler and  `iframeHandler.evaluate( element=> element )`  passes element handle as the first argument to pageFunction.

Answer (score 0):

So I found it :

according to doc

> elementHandle.contentFrame()
>   returns: `<Promise<?Frame>>` Resolves to the content frame for element handles referencing iframe nodes, or null otherwise

so

```js
iframeHandler = await page.$('ifram#id')
frame = iframeHandler.contentFrame()
frame.evaluate( _=> 'run some code')
```